# Codeigniter Model Parse Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a new site and it includes database, as it said every time you want to access your database you need to do it in your Model but I don't know why I am having a problem with my Model. Please the codes below.

Controller:main

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home(){
        $this->announce($data);
    }
    public function announce(){
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->model('home_model');
        //echo "test";

    }
```

Model:home_model.php

```
class Home_model extends CI_Model{
    echo '';
}
```

after running the program. localhost/ci_gcc/main/announce or localhost/ci_gcc/main I got this error.

**Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_FUNCTION' in C:\wamp\www\ci_gcc\application\models\home_model.php on line 4**

but if I didn't type anything inside the model class there is no error.
Thus anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Problem solved. I forgot the function announce_table(){
     $this->load->database();
     $query = $this->db->get('announcement'); //test is my table 
     foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {
     echo $row->title;
     echo $row->date;
     echo $row->venue;
     echo $row->content;
  }
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a bad attempt. Don't echo like this in model class.

```
$this->load->model('home_model');
```

This will load your model class. Inorder to do any operations inside the model class, you have to write functions inside it. And you can call that function from your controller like,.

```
$this->home_model->functionname();
```

Comment: Sorry About that. yes indeed. thank you for the correction. much appreciated. :)